# angularjs syntax error unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

var solvedOptionOther = "\'" +"#"+ a + "\'";

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#option2

this is my function--

```
 if ($scope.solvedQuestionId.contains(otherQuestionID)) {

         $scope.otherid= otherQuestionID;
         var optionIndex =   $scope.solvedQuestionId.indexOf(parseInt($scope.otherid)) + 1;
         $scope.optionOtherIndex =  optionIndex;
         var a =  $scope.solvedQuestionId[optionIndex]
         var solvedOptionOther = "\'" +"#"+ a + "\'";
         alert(solvedOptionOther);

         $(".option").css("border","none");
     /* $("#" +$scope.optionOtherIndex).css("border","none");*/

        $('.option').css('pointer-events','none');
        $("#" +$scope.answersOfQuestion.answer).css("border","green solid   2px");
         alert("solved");
         $(solvedOptionOther).css("border","red solid 2px");


     }
```

Comment: what is your question ? we can suppose several things but you have to be more precise

Comment: var solvedOptionOther = "\'" +"#"+ a + "\'"; (Getting Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression ) on this line

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to wrap it in single quotes

If you hardcode what you are doing, you would have this selector: `$("'#option2'")`.

All you need is:

```
var solvedOptionOther = "#"+ a;
```